# Office.js Taskpane UI is not responsive mouse shows waiting cursor while data is printed in excel

Tags: office-js

i am developing an excel office addin using office.js, i get lot of data from backend server which i want to display on excel. I use

```
Range.values = [formatted data for excel range]
```

i place the values in chunk of 5000 and when context sync is called, IE or Desktop excel become so responsive that it cannot be used.

what is the minimum no of data point should be placed using `Range.values` so that UI is responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ExcelApi 1.3 (currently in beta, but should be going to "prod" in the coming weeks), we have added a special helper that chunks the values into smaller subsets and sets those individually, to prevent Excel from becoming unresponsive.

You can try it using https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/Office.js.

Depending on your timeline (is this for something you've already shipped, or something you're still developing), you might just wait for the Beta to move to Prod, and so you can use the Beta CDN for development for now.  Just be sure that you're on the latest (or at least, recent) monthly fork of Excel.  Note that for now Excel will report `isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.3)` as false, since it's technically a "beta".  But the next month's release (whenever that happens) will have that set to true, at which point it will be officially live and we'll promote it into the prod CDN.

If you can't wait, you can implement your own chunking mechanism.  See https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.debug.js, and search for setRangePropertiesInBulk within it.  In our experimentation, we found that ~1,500 was a pretty good number, so we use that... But I'd love to hear what your experience with this is, and we can certainly adjust that number accordingly.

Comment: hi Michael, is it possible for you to make only taskpane responsive, while excel write operation is going on. i have a cancel button on taskpane which cancels the excel write operation but its not clickable because taskpane is not responsive.

Comment: Are you using the chunking mechanism, or setting values as is?  (BTW, I think I was wrong about the 1.3 beta doing chunks for you right now -- the code is there in JS, but it is effectively "dark" until a newer version of the desktop client comes out.  But you can still write something very similar yourself, just don't include the "isExcel1_3OrAbove" check or the "_ValidateArraySize" call.

Comment: Note that even with chunking, you're unlikely to be able to click "cancel" and have it do anything, as at that point the call is already dispatched to Excel, and so it will proceed to try to execute it, even if it no longer looks frozen.  But at least from a UX perspective, Excel won't look like it's not responding.

Comment: If you truly want to be able to cancel, you'll need to send the values in batches (multiple ctx.sync-s), so that clicking "cancel" along the way can stop the JS from sending any new batches.  Once something is sent over the wire to the host, it will be executed to completion, unless something in the batch errors out.